# Cosa significa "foglio di via" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Natale a Marradi: l'ultimo Natale di Dino Campana*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Invece i documenti c'erano e Tizio lo sapeva bene. Fortunatamente per me, non tutti erano importanti. C'era la minutaglia di carte che si può trovare in un Comune, a proposito di un cittadino nato e residente; c'erano parecchi «**fogli di via**» dell'autorità di Pubblica Sicurezza; c'era la chiamata alle armi per la leva (ma Dino, a vent'anni, il servizio militare lo aveva già fatto come volontario).

Il brano fa riferimento ai documenti trovati dallo scrittore nel municipio di Marradi, paese natale di Dino Campana. Non capisco il significato di "fogli di via" in questo passaggio.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/foglio/) ho trovato queste definizioni di "foglio di via":

> *F. di via*, documento provvisorio rilasciato dall’Ispettorato della motorizzazione civile, che consente la circolazione delle vetture non ancora immatricolate e per le quali non è stata ancora pagata la tassa di circolazione. Con altro senso, *f. di via*, o *di viaggio*, documento di viaggio gratuito rilasciato in particolari casi a militari oppure a persone che, in stato di necessità, devono rientrare al paese d’origine o recarsi in una località determinata; *f. di via obbligatorio*, documento col quale il questore può disporre il rimpatrio, cioè il rinvio al luogo di residenza, di persone sottoposte a diffida e ritenute pericolose per la sicurezza pubblica o la pubblica moralità (il provvedimento implica l’inibizione a ritornare nel comune dal quale sono state allontanate).

Tuttavia, non riesco a vedere a quale o quali accezioni possano corrispondere i "fogli di via" che appaiono nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'accezione è l'ultima indicata dal vocabolario Treccani. In [questa pagina](http://www.campanadino.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=282:il-foglio-di-via-da-genova-29-marzo-1913&catid=33:biografia&Itemid=58) si può vedere la riproduzione di uno dei fogli di via che Dino Campana ha ricevuto durante la sua vita, per i comportamenti giudicati "strani" o violenti o perturbatori dell'ordine pubblico.

Comment: Cioè, in questo esempio, significa che Campana veniva rinviato da Genova a Marradi?

Comment: Esatto. Significa che Campana non poteva più stare a Genova ed era obbligato a rientrare a Marradi, il suo luogo di residenza.